# How to set up ngrok for Teams Tab cross-device debug

Tags: visual-studio-code, microsoft-teams, ngrok, teams-toolkit

I've verified that ngrok works in my set up by changing the manifest.json file. However, there is an issue with obtaining the SSO token in two different ways.

Firstly, the resource URL is different from the iframe. Secondly, changing the resource URL would cause a mismatch with Azure AD. Changing the Application ID URI within AAD does not help as this is where I noticed that the URI within AAD is rewritten, as with the local.env and default.userdata.

May I know if anyone has a workaround or a workflow to set up ngrok to allow cross-device debugging?

Comment: @ChetanSharma-msft Yes! It's been resolved, thank you for commenting on this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Application ID Uri, there is workaround. You can try to add two new configs (domain and endpoint) under "fx-resource-aad-app-for-teams" in "env.default.json" as shown
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pj5fm.png)

Comment: Hey there! Thanks for helping out! I managed to get it to work by using the skipProvision flag to prevent it from updating the URI while switching out the URLs within the manifest to point toward the ngrok url